# Detection of NaN assignement in a whole java program

Tags: java, debugging

I have a program that generates double values. Some of my result are NaN which is not supposed to happen and i'd like to know where in the code NaN are assigned.
I'd like to not be forced to test `Double.isNaN` at every step of the program. The best scenario would be to have a way to have an exception thrown when a NaN value is assigned like it is done when you try to call a method from a null object.

Edit: OK obviously my question wasn't clear.
My program create objects that have double values. Those values are changed millions of time thanks to several methods that manipulate the object. The question is, am I forced to check if the value is NaN in every method that modify the value, or is there a way to detect when NaN is assigned in the whole program.

Comment: I quite don't understand. Can't you just loop double generation as: do generate double while generated is NaN  ?

Comment: There are tools like quickcheck that *generate* test data in very smart ways. Maybe you could use that to write special unit tests that reveal which operation ends up computing to NaN.

Answer (score 2):

There is no fast solution to this. You do need to use `Double.isNaN`, in the same way that you check data for `null`.

The trick to not doing the checks everywhere is placing them in a few "strategic spots" to facilitate the "fail fast" approach. For example, if you construct objects that have `double`s in them, add checks to the constructor:

```
private final double val;
public MyObject(double val) {
    if (Double.isNaN(val)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.val = val;
}
```

If you encapsulate your data properly and do parameter checking along the way, your code should be able to trap `NaN`s pretty close to spots where they are being set, helping you diagnose and fix the problem.